# Make Command Only Visible When a Handler is Present

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I know I can make commands visible like that:

```
     <command commandId="org.acme.command" style="push">
        <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
           <with variable="selection">
              <test property="someProperty"
                    value="value">
              </test>
           </with>
        </visibleWhen>
     </command>
```

But how can I make a command only visible when there is a handler that is able to handle it? (The default behavior is for the command to be present, but disabled.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a hack, but hooking this property tester to the command helps:

```
public class HandlerEnabledTester extends PropertyTester {

private static final String PROPERTY_HANDLER_ENABLED = "handlerEnabled";

@Override
public boolean test(final Object receiver, final String property, final Object[] args, final Object expectedValue) {
    if (PROPERTY_HANDLER_ENABLED.equals(property)) {
        return isHandlerEnabled((String) expectedValue);
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isHandlerEnabled(String commandId) {
    ICommandService commandService = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(ICommandService.class);
    Command command = commandService.getCommand(commandId);
    return command.isEnabled();
}
}
```

Aaand:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters">
  <propertyTester
        class="org.acme.HandlerEnabledTester"
        id="org.acme.HandlerEnabledTester"
        namespace="scope"
        properties="handlerEnabled"
        type="org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection">
  </propertyTester>
</extension>

...

<command commandId="org.acme.command" style="push">
  <visibleWhen checkEnabled="false">
    <with variable="selection">
      <test property="scope.handlerEnabled"
            value="org.acme.command">
      </test>
    </with>
  </visibleWhen>
</command>
```